# Crash приложения Spring Boot при использовании lambda выражений

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

При использовании `lambda` выражений в любом из классов приложения получаю ошибку при старте приложения.

Запуск такого кода:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(
                HibernateConfig.class,
                AppConfig.class,
                ServerConfig.class
        );
        ctx.refresh();

        new ArrayList<>().forEach(o -> {
        });
    }
}
```

привод к:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build
>   ClassFile     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   com.common.Application.main(Application.java:26) [main/:na] Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build
>   ClassFile     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:88)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:65)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:167)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:142)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:142)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:142)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:78)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:72)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:723)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:219)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:186)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]    at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     ... 16 common
>   frames omitted

Но если убрать из кода строчку:

```
new ArrayList<>().forEach(o -> {});
```

то приложение запуститься без ошибок.

**build.gradle**

```
group 'SpringBootExample'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName ="com.common.Application"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'




    //---------


    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.3.6.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.3.6.Final'



    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
//    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7'
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.15.0-GA'
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.0-801.jdbc4'
    compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
}
```

Вопрос: чем может быть вызвано такое поведение, и как это исправить?

Comment: [тут](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8899) пишут, что проблема с `javassist` и работает версия `3.18.2-GA`

Comment: получилось устранить проблема добавлением аннотации @EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class})

Comment: @KirillStoianov а какая именно проблема и как разрешилось?